# Git works using Git bash in terminal, but not in VS code

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, terminal

Working in Visual Studio Code I'm using Git to manage my files. I use SSH to have a secure connection. When working with files in file explorer and using the git bash terminal everything works fine. However, when I use git with Visual Studio Code I get the following error:

```
> git pull --tags origin master
  git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights 
  and the repository exists.
```

Using the Git bash terminal (thus without VS Code) everything works smoothly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to rule it out, are you *sure* both are running in the same repo (local working directory)?

Comment: @TTT Good observation! Yes, I'm really sure it's the same repo

Comment: Did it ever work in VSCode? Some ideas (or bad news) [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115371), [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4244), and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13680).

Comment: You need to make sure you have the same credentials set up in whatever shell VSCode is using (PowerShell by default).

Comment: Did you verifyy, that in your VS Code case, you also run git-bash?

Comment: @user1934428 How can I verify this?

Comment: Do a `echo $BASH_VERSION`. If you get a reasonable response, you not only can be pretty sure that you run bash, but also which version of bash you have. Another possibility (a bit of a hack) is to just enter a closed parenthese (`)`). From the error message you get, you can most likely infer which shell is running.

Comment: It looks like the environment VSCode sets up is missing some bits ssh needs. If you're running an ssh agent that's probably it, ssh uses environment variables to look for a running ssh agent.

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot of different terminal options]

For Visual Studio terminal window - the default shell is powershell, now if your git-bash setup is working outside of VS Code using git-bash, then you need to setup the VS code - terminal - default shell as git-bash. Steps - When under VS code you open the terminal window or terminal opens up under the code section - you will see tabs like OUTPUT, TERMINAL, GITLENS, DEBUG CONSOLE etc. On the exterme right you should see a "+" sign and if you drop down you will see multiple options - default is powershell, others are command prompt, git-bash, java-debug terminal etc. You can choose git-bash to resolve the issue shown here.